# How do I add new lines to a Perl script using PPI?

Tags: perl

What I'd ideally like to be able to do is scan a bunch of files that are implicitly importing a bunch of functions via `Test::Most`.  I'd like to explicitly import the functions within the file.  So basically I'll check the `use` statements to see if they already exist and, if they don't, I'd like to add an additional use statement for the function(s) in question.  For example, I might add `use Test::Differences qw( eq_or_diff );` if there's an `eq_or_diff` in the file, but no `use Test::Differences`.  It'll get a little more complicated, but that's the basic idea.

As a proof of concept, I've tried to add just a single word into an existing script, but I can't figure it out. `insert_after()` returns true on success.  I only ever get a `false` value, but I don't see any debugging info as to why the line could not be added.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PPI::Document ();
use PPI::Token::Word ();
use Test::More;

my $script = <<'EOF';
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime ();
use Git::Helpers qw( checkout_root );
use LWP::UserAgent ();

my $foo = 'bar';
EOF

my $doc = PPI::Document->new( \$script );

my $includes    = $doc->find('PPI::Statement::Include');
my @use         = grep { $_->type eq 'use' } @{$includes};
my $second_last = $use[-2];

diag 'Trying to insert after ' . $second_last->module;

my $word = PPI::Token::Word->new('use');
isa_ok( $word,        'PPI::Element', 'word is an Element' );
isa_ok( $second_last, 'PPI::Element', 'use is an Element' );

ok( $second_last->insert_after($word), 'word inserted' );

diag $doc->serialize;

done_testing();
```

The output of my script is as follows.  You'll note that the document does not appear to have been altered:

```
# trying to insert after Git::Helpers
ok 1 - 'word is an Element' isa 'PPI::Element'
ok 2 - 'use is an Element' isa 'PPI::Element'
not ok 3 - word inserted
#   failed test 'word inserted'
#   at so.pl line 31.
# use strict;
# use warnings;
#
# use DateTime ();
# use Git::Helpers qw( checkout_root );
# use LWP::UserAgent ();
#
# my $foo = 'bar';
1..3
# looks like you failed 1 test of 3.
```

Comment: The documentation says that `insert_after` does some syntax checking and prevents inserting wrong code. You probably need to insert a whole `PPI::Statement::Include`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [source of `PPI::Statement`](https://metacpan.org/source/PPI::Statement):

```
# As above, you can insert a statement, or a non-significant token
sub insert_after {
        my $self    = shift;
        my $Element = _INSTANCE(shift, 'PPI::Element') or return undef;
        if ( $Element->isa('PPI::Statement') ) {
                return $self->__insert_after($Element);
        } elsif ( $Element->isa('PPI::Token') and ! $Element->significant ) {
                return $self->__insert_after($Element);
        }
        '';
}
```

A "non-significant token" is something like whitespace or a comment.

You are trying to insert a single, significant token at the top level (after a statement). That's not allowed.

You'll have to build a full `PPI::Statement::Include` element.

---

Here's some (rather ugly) proof-of-concept code:

```
# ...
diag 'Trying to insert after ' . $second_last->module;

{
    my $insertion_point = $second_last;
    for my $new_element (
        do {
            my $synthetic_use = PPI::Statement::Include->new;
            for my $child (
                PPI::Token::Word->new('use'),
                PPI::Token::Whitespace->new(' '),
                PPI::Token::Word->new('Test::Differences'),
                PPI::Token::Whitespace->new(' '),
                PPI::Token::Quote::Single->new("'eq_or_diff'"),
                PPI::Token::Structure->new(';'),
            ) {
                ok $synthetic_use->add_element($child);
            }
            $synthetic_use
        },
        PPI::Token::Whitespace->new("\n"),
    ) {
        ok $insertion_point->insert_after($new_element);
    }
}

diag $doc->serialize;
```

But it's much easier to let PPI parse a given fragment and just use those objects:

```
diag 'Trying to insert after ' . $second_last->module;

{
    my $insertion_point = $second_last;
    for my $new_element (
        reverse PPI::Document->new(\ "\nuse Test::Differences qw( eq_or_diff );")->elements
    ) {
        ok $insertion_point->insert_after($new_element->remove);
    }
}

diag $doc->serialize;
```

Beware: Using `$new_element->remove` instead of just `$new_element` is crucial. You need to detach `$new_element` from its old containing document because otherwise the destruction of the temporary `PPI::Document` instance will wipe out all child elements, including those already added to `$doc`.

Comment: You can use the PPI parser to generate the statement. `my $use_doc = PPI::Document->new(\"use Test::Differences;"); my $include = ($doc2->children)[0];`

Comment: @Schwern That's exactly what I'm working on now. :-)

Comment: @Schwern It looks like the destruction of my temporary `PPI::Document` is wiping out my parsed elements, but I'm still debugging.